# Why Anonymous access option disabled in SharePoint site?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, anonymous

I have set up the SharePoint 2010 with windows7 by following the steps given [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869%28office.14%29.aspx).

I am trying to give the antonymous access to the default site (80 port). followed [here](http://www.topsharepoint.com/enable-anonymous-access-in-sharepoint-2010).

as i went to step 8, i found the Anonymous Access option for the site is disabled. I logged in with administrator. as usual there should be permissible for administrator. Why should this is happening?

Also Can I make Central admin to anonymous access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this might be helpful to you :

In Central Administration -> select your web application -> than in Ribbon tab you can see User Policy tab click on it and add your site administrator with full control. than check it.

Let me know if it helps